# Apply keyframe animation relative to existing translate3D

Tags: css

I'm quite not sure how to approach this.
I have a div that has its position controlled with using inline style from javascript, ie:

```
<div style="transform: translate3d(20px, 40px, 0);"></div>
```

I have a generic "shake" animation as follow

```
.shake{
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-origin: center;
}
@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translateX(-2px);
    }  
    20%, 80% {
        transform: translateX(4px);
    }
    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translateX(-8px);
    }
    40%, 60% {
        transform: translateX(8px);
    }
}
```

If I apply my css class to the div, it will relocate the div to the top left of the screen. Is there a way to add to the existing translate3d from the animation, maybe with calc() ?
Ideally I'd like to do (pseudo code)

```
 @keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translateX(@current_translate_x - 2px);
    }  
    ....
```

Comment: I'm not clear about x and y. Are they continuously changing? What sets them? Can you provide an MRE?

Comment: Can't believe I can't find the dupe for this. I'm sure there are a lot and even one I already answered somewhere... @Temani I leave it to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an [`animation-composition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-composition) rule that you can set to tell how the properties set during the animation should affect the same properties already set before the animation:

```css
.shake {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
  
:checked + .shake {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-origin: center;
    animation-composition: add;
}
@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translateX(-2px);
    }  
    20%, 80% {
        transform: translateX(4px);
    }
    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translateX(-8px);
    }
    40%, 60% {
        transform: translateX(8px);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
<div class="shake" style="transform: translate3d(20px, 40px, 0);"></div>
```

If browser support is too low for you, then you can also achieve the same by using the [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate) property instead of  `transform: translate()`, both will add up:

```css
.shake {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
  
:checked + .shake {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-origin: center;
}
@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translateX(-2px);
    }  
    20%, 80% {
        transform: translateX(4px);
    }
    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translateX(-8px);
    }
    40%, 60% {
        transform: translateX(8px);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
<!-- Note how we now use the 'translate' property -->
<div class="shake" style="translate: 20px 40px;"></div>
```

If it's still too edgy for you, you could still resort to the old good wrap in container and transform said container:

```css
.shake-container > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
  
:checked + .shake-container  > div {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-origin: center;
}
@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translateX(-2px);
    }  
    20%, 80% {
        transform: translateX(4px);
    }
    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translateX(-8px);
    }
    40%, 60% {
        transform: translateX(8px);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
<!-- we set the initial transform on the container -->
<div class="shake-container" style="transform: translate3d(20px, 40px, 0);">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I think @kaiido's answers are better, here is one way of doing it using more the kind of structure you envisaged in the question - using CSS calc and introducing CSS variables for more flexibility:

```css
.shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(var(--x) - 2px), var(--y), var(--z));
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(var(--x) + 4px), var(--y), var(--z));
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(var(--x) - 8px), var(--y), var(--z));
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(var(--x) + 8px), var(--y), var(--z));
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="--x: 20px; --y: 40px; --z: 0; transform: translate3d(var(--x), var(--y), var(--z));" class="shake">abc</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was exploring the same idea before he posted :) thanks anyway